# How does $\frac{xy}{A}=\frac{1}{bcK}+\frac{x+y}{bc}$ become $\frac{A}{xy} = bcK - \frac{A(x+y)K}{xy}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, chemistry

As part of a derivation for a formula I was given the following:

$$\frac{xy}{A} = \frac{1}{bcK} + \frac{x+y}{bc} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{A}{xy} = bcK - \frac{A(x+y)K}{xy}$$

Where $b$, $c$, and $K$ are all constants (I've replaced most chemistry symbols with something more readable). The idea here is that by varying $x$ or $y$, and measuring $A$, you are able to determine $K$ (equilibrium constant) from the slope.

I was told the rearrangement involved some less user friendly maths, so I made a few attempts with little success. How is this rearrangement done? And what is the "less user friendly maths" used in this situation?

Comment: As for what makes this "less user friendly maths" ... It's hard to say. The steps are elementary enough. Maybe the person telling you this is observing that the left-hand sides of the two equations alone *might* seem to be suggesting that "all you have to do" is reciprocate, whereas the actual procedure isn't quite so simple (or "user friendly") as *that*.

Comment: Think that's where I went wrong to begin with. Seems fairly user friendly now that I've seen it. Thanks for the help @Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{xy}{A} & =\frac{1}{bcK} + \frac{x+y}{bc}\\
 & = \frac{1+(x+y)K}{bcK} \\
\implies bcK &=\left(1+(x+y)K\right)\left(\frac{A}{xy}\right)\\
&=\frac{A}{xy}+{A(x+y)K\over xy}\\
\implies \frac{A}{xy} &= bcK - \frac{A(x+y)K}{xy}\end{align}